# Where is Weight Paint?

Tags: weight-painting

How can I activate the Weight Paint?

I'm a completelly new user and all the Tutorials I find shows in the same place I'm trying on the picture, please what am I doing wrong?

[image: Place it should be appearing]

Comment: Select the mesh, not the bones/armature

Comment: In the Edit menu disable the Lock Object Modes option (so that you can keep your armature in Pöse mode), keep the bone selected, shift select the mesh, switch it to Weight Paint mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to Tab into OBJECT mode. From there, if you grab the drop down window (that you note in your screenshot), Weight Paint should be available.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but I had to deparent, but it was your answer that gave the tip.

Comment: Good enough for me! Good luck!